# Program gives me wrong output, can someone take a look?

Tags: c++

So here's the question:
An office starts its work on 8:00:00 and employees may leave on 17:00:00.
Write an OOP program that gets the time that an employee enters and exits.
If an employee comes later than 8:10:00, program should say that the employee has delayed and if sooner than that, it should say that the employee was on time. If one exits later than 17:30:00, the program should say that the employee has stayed  an overtime and if sooner than that, the program should say that the employee has exited on time .
So here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class wTime
{
public:
    void get_entime(int, int, int);
    void get_extime(int, int, int);
    bool calc_en();
    bool calc_ex();
    void show_result();
private:
    int h1, m1, s1;
    int h2, m2, s2;
};
void wTime::get_entime(int x=8,int y=0, int z=0)
{
    x = h1;
    y = m1;
    z = s1;
    cout << "Enter the entry time in 24 hour format (hh mm ss): " << endl;
    cin >> x >> y >> z;
}
void wTime::get_extime(int a=17, int b=0, int c=0)
{
    a = h2;
    b = m2;
    c = s2;
    cout << "Enter the exit time in 24 hour format: (hh mm ss) : " << endl;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
}
bool wTime::calc_en()
{

    if (h1 > 8)
        return true;//takhir dashte;
    if (h1 == 8 && m1 > 10 )
        return true;//takhir dashte;
    if (h1 < 8)
        return false;//on time boode;
    if (h1 == 8 && m1 < 9)
        return false;//on time boode;
}
bool wTime::calc_ex()
{
    if (h2 > 17)
        return true;//ezafe kari dashte;
    if (h2 >= 17 && m2 >= 30)
        return true;//ezafe kari nadashte
    if (h2 == 17 && m2 < 30)
        return false;
}
void wTime::show_result()
{
    if (calc_en() == true)
        cout << "Employee has delayed." << endl;
    if (calc_en() == false)
        cout << "Employee was on time" << endl;
    if (calc_ex() == true)
        cout << "Employee has stayed an overtime" << endl;
    if (calc_ex() == false)
        cout << "Employee has exited on time." << endl;
}
int main()
{
    wTime em;
    em.get_entime();
    em.calc_en();
    em.get_extime();
    em.calc_ex();
    em.show_result();
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that, for every hh mm ss that I enter it just returns 
Employee has delayed.
Employee has exited on time.
What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? Take a look at [MCVE], try to track this down to a single method call that's causing you issues - I'm pretty confident that you'll be able to find the problem pretty easily if you do that, but if it proves harder *then* you should come back to SO and ask a question about that trimmed down version of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you take the user input via `cin`, you're putting it in local variables (specifically the function parameters) which get destroyed immediately afterwards. You're not actually storing them for the subsequent calculations.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
void wTime::get_entime()
{
    cout << "Enter the entry time in 24 hour format (hh mm ss): " << endl;
    cin >> h1 >> m1 >> s1;
}
```

(Do the equivalent for `get_extime()` too). That will store the values in the member variables so that they can be used in the calculation methods.

Comment: Looks like he thinks `a=h2` binds the two together. To OP: to do that you need pointers. And no, that wouldn't be a good thing to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool wTime::calc_en()
{ 
    if (h1 > 8)
        return true;//takhir dashte;
    if (h1 == 8 && m1 > 10 )
        return true;//takhir dashte;
    if (h1 < 8)
        return false;//on time boode;
    if (h1 == 8 && m1 < 9)
        return false;//on time boode;
}
```

you should put in a default return value

for example 8:10 or 8:09 don't get evaluated (the same problem exists in wTime::calc_ex)

and of course the previously mentioned input problems